# Recyclerview with X items and View more button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to know if there is any way how to implement RecyclerView with only part of the collection. For example, the ArrayList would have 10 bitmaps in it, but only 6 can fit the screen without scrolling. So I want to show only 5 of them, and the 6th would be a clickable Button/ImageView which would say 'View 5 more'.

Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: it is possible..nobody can really tell you accurately unless you can provide some code of what you have tried to accomplish.

Comment: I know what you mean, but so far I have just a simple implementation of RecyclerView with 1 ImageView in each row. So there is nothing to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be having 2 lists in your adapter, one is the list that you actually show (show list) and the other one the full dataset. as long as you're not showing the full dataset, add a row at the end with the button show more, when clicking the button add a new batch of items from the full dataset to the show list.

Comment: i was just thinking the same. Is there a way to fill X items from the first list based on space? I want to disable scrolling.

Comment: hum, not that I know of. I think that is something that should be handled by the layout manager though

Comment: it seems to me that it will be unnecessarily complicated, so i might just ditch the idea and keep the scrolling.

Comment: I will check, I just remembered that I did it at some point. The layout manager has the possibility of measure the items. If I recall how I did it I will post some code. Unfortunately I take NDAs too seriously haha